# AWS ELB -> nginx -> socket.io node.js sticky load balancing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing

I am having an issue with this configuration. My AWS ELB accepts TCP connections on port 80 and forwards them using proxy protocol to an nginx instance listening on port 8080. This nginx node is supposed to use ip_hash module to stick the user to a specific node.

This is working perfectly fine, but only 2 out of the 4 nodes are being used instead of being load balanced among all of them, here is my nginx config

```
upstream socket_nodes {
    ip_hash;
    server a.server.com:2000;
    server a.server.com:2001;
    server a.server.com:2002;
    server a.server.com:2003;
}

# Accept connections via the load balancer
server {
  listen 8080 proxy_protocol;
  set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/32;
  real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
  charset utf-8;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Comment: ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike "round robin" loading balancing, ip_hash means that for any given IP address, NGINX will always forward to the same application instance.